# Is a primary key required? (6NF implementation)

Tags: database, postgresql, normalization

Is a primary key required in the 6NF relvar tables of a 5NF relation. Consider the following setup:

```
-- The 5NF table
CREATE TABLE party_address(
    address_id int NOT NULL,
    party_id int NOT NULL,
    -- some other columns
    PRIMARY KEY (address_id, party_id)
);

CREATE TABLE party_address_is_billing(
    address_id int NOT NULL,
    party_id int NOT NULL,
    value boolean NOT NULL,
    transaction_time tstzrange NOT NULL DEFAULT tstzrange(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, '[)'),
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (address_id WITH =, party_id WITH =, transaction_time WITH &&)
);
```

Is it required to explicitly declare `PRIMARY KEY` on the `party_address_is_billing` table? Since the exclusion constraint specifies a unique identifier (`(address_id, party_id, transaction_time)`), it seems redundant to explicitly specify `PRIMARY KEY (address_id, party_id, transaction_time)`. It would also create an additional and unnecessary index.

- What are the consequences of not specifying `PRIMARY KEY` on a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relational model requires that every relation have at least one key. It doesn't require you to use particular keywords.

In your 5NF table, if you declare the key as `not null unique (address_id, party_id)`, you won't alter the underlying dependencies at all. And that's what you have to be concerned about from the relational point of view--that alternative syntax doesn't screw up the underlying dependencies. (Which means the relational model isn't concerned with an implementation's "additional and unnecessary index".)

So, in "party_address_is_billing", if the exclusion constraint behaves like a key constraint, I think you're fine as far as the relational model is concerned.

> What are the consequences of not specifying PRIMARY KEY on a table?

1. If you replace a primary key constraint with another declarative constraint that's behaviorally identical, you might surprise maintenance programmers. See the article [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).
2. You might also make framework programmers work harder. Many frameworks require not just a PRIMARY KEY constraint, they also require that constraint be a surrogate integer. (This isn't really a relational issue.)
3. Some software engineering (CASE) tools might choke on an exclusion constraint.
4. The error message associated with a process that violates an exclusion constraint might be less clear than an error message about a violation of a primary key constraint. (This is related to "1", above.)

I don't think there are *any* consequences as far as the relational model is concerned. (That is, as long as you replace a primary key constraint with a declarative constraint that's behaviorally identical.)